# In a circular path, whats the difference between centrifugal force and the normal force between the object and the surface?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Im getting extremely confused. [In this discussion with someone](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/457927/a-mass-is-rolling-down-a-curved-path?noredirect=1#comment1027811_457927) it turns out that the Normal force IS in fact the centrifugal force which is applied on the object, but then, what is keeping the object from going through the track? I dont know if this is confusing to you guys, but my final is tomorrow and im really worried because this seems very fundamental and im supposed to know this but ive gotten it all confused somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It's never correct to say that the normal force is the centrifugal force.

You could say the normal force is the  centripetal force. The centripetal force isn't some new kind of force, it's just the net force acting towords the center of rotation (perpendicular to the velocity).  It's not uncommon for the centripetal force to be a combination of forces for instance gravity and the normal force (working together or in opposition) like in the ball on the curvy ramp problem you're alluding to.

The centrifugal force is different from the centripetal force in more ways than just it's direction. It arises in a rotating (noninertial) frame of reference. You can calculate it based on the object's mass and location with respect to the centre of rotation. Unlike the centripetal force, the centrifugal force *isn't* some other force playing a role. It's a force of its own.